# Does primer normally separate in to different colors, or is this mold growing in it?

Tags: painting, paint, mold, primer

I have two five gallon buckets of Sherwin Williams PVA Drywall Primer & Sealer which is about a year and a half old. One is a partial bucket and the other is sealed and has never been opened.

I just opened them and they both have two small colored areas separated and floating near the top.  One is orange and the other is green:

[image: photo of primer with colored areas]

I assumed that it was mold when I opened the partial bucket, but when the unused bucket had it too, I started to wonder if this was normal.

Is this primer bad or can it be used like it is?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/18133/46271.   It will probably be fine just stir really well before using.  See the link for related info.

Comment: @kris Thanks, but what about the colored stuff in it?  If it wasn't for that, I wouldn't have even questioned it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primer-unbdercoat often has a higher pigment content than topcoat paint, this helps it cover marked surfaces better. usually the pigments are a combionation of carbon black and titanium oxide white.

When left to stand the different pigments will separate at different rates giving a mottled result like you show above.  just give it a really good stir. Not ten laps with a popsicle stick, a it'll take a really good stir to mix the settled pigment back into the resin.  I use a bent wire in an electric drill.

Comment: I've taken older paint back to the store where I bought it and they put it on the shaker machine for me.

Comment: I have a helix paint stir that fits a 1/2” drill it works well and I fully agree with a good stir.+

Comment: I have a small one from a coat-hanger bent into a sort of 'J' shape for small cans, and large one from re-bar for large pots. I don't paint often enough to purchase one of those helix ones